# polar coordinates integral equation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\phi$ be a k- times differentiable function. Prove that the following holds:
>
> $\int_{t_o}^{t_1}(\alpha_1(s)\dot \alpha_2(s)- \alpha_2(s)\dot \alpha_1(s))ds=\phi(t_1)-\phi(t_o)$ where $\alpha(s)=(\cos(\phi(s)),\sin(\phi(s)))$

I guess I would only need to show that $\dot \phi(s)=\alpha_1(s)\dot \alpha_2(s)-\alpha_2(s)\dot \alpha_1(s)$ but I dont know how.

Would appreciate help/hints

Comment: Why not differentiate $\alpha(s)$ (correctly) and check?

Comment: Observe that what you "only need to show" is zero. There's a mistake in the indices there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\alpha=(\cos\phi,\,\sin\phi)\implies\dot\alpha=(-\dot\phi\sin\phi,\,\dot\phi\cos\phi)$$

and thus (with the expression already corrected)

$$\alpha_1\dot\alpha_2-\dot\alpha_1\alpha_2=\dot\phi\cos^2\phi+\dot\phi\sin^2\phi=\dot\phi$$